# LINQ groupby to List<List<object>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an ASP.NET MVC view where I'm using LINQ to split a model into multiple lists of an object.

The code below works in that I get the correct list of objects in `var data` but I cannot then cast it to my object to access the properties. I get error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Grouping[<>f__AnonymousType3'2[System.DateTime,System.String],MVCProj.Models.tblData2017]'
>   to type 'MVCProj.Models.tblData2017

Index.cshtml View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCProj.Models.tblData2017>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Title</h2>
@{
    var data = Model.Where(x => x.Start.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Start, x.Field2 }).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        var rowItem = (List<tblCards2017>)data[i]; //<-Error on this line
        string header1 = $"{rowItem.Start.ToString("HH:mm")} {rowItem.Field2}";
    }
}
```

How can I do either of the following

i) Successfully cast `var rowItem = (List<tblCards2017>)data[i];`

or

ii) Use linq to get the correct object type `List<List<tblCards2017> data = Model.Where.....` instead of the current type `var data = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType2<System.DateTime, string>, MVCProj.Models.tblData2017>>`

Comment: You don't need to create a list of it and use `foreach` on it.  You just did a grouping, so you need to create 2 iterations. (foreach loop inside a foreach loop)

Comment: When you do a `GroupBy` you get a collection of `IGrouping` objects that have a `Key` based on what you grouped on and is itself a collection of the items you grouped.  So `var rowItem = data[i].ToList();` is likely what you want.  But if `rowItem` is suppose to be a `List` then it's not going to have a `Start` or `Field2` properties.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - the controller is just lifting straight fdrom a db table using `public async Task<ActionResult> Index() { return View(await db.tblData2017.ToListAsync()); }`

Comment: @pathDongle It's stange, you're talking about a list, but you're accessing the Key values. Seems preposterous. The example is not complete. Whats below the `string header1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking this:

```
var data = Model.Where(x => x.Start.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Start, x.Field2 })
                .Select(g=>g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Add a `Select` call to get a list per each group